# right way to change xmodmap

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

My `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_R
add mod1 = Alt_R
```

my `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
    /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi
```

Why am I not able to change my xmodmap?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do?  Your code shows that you remove mod1 then you add it right back to mod1, so technically there would be no change.  But when I look at posts like this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58145 they're reassigning them to different mods.

Comment: @Terrance you solved the riddle!!! Thank you, I'm blind!